# How to get parent's controller_name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using `controller.controller_name` to see where I'm at, and set the `active` class on my menu.

The problem is I have a `namespace: :admin` in my routes... and I need to check if I'm in any controller which inherits from `AdminController`. Right now, `controller_name` only pulls up the child controller's name... but really I need it to say 'admin'.

How can I access the name of the controller it's inheriting from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `parent`:

```
controller.class.parent
```

Comment: I like this the best, but how do I check if it matches `Admin`? `.instance_of?` and `.type_of` don't seem to be working

Comment: @Tallboy `==` will work if you call `to_s` on it, otherwise it will no work properly.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could do:

```
controller.class.superclass
```

This should return `AdminController` if your current controller is indeed inheriting from `AdminController`.

Also, `controller.class` should give you the fully namespaced controller name.

Answer (score 1):

Try `controller.ancestors.include?(AdminController)`